# Unable to search the data using query or update _by_query in a newly created index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Created an index tr_logintracker in elasticsearch using the below. We are using Elasticsearch version 7.17
We even tried with data type of Integer in place of index

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "logintime": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "logouttime": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "logout": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "vehicleid": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "driverid": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "vehicleownerid": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index is created

```json
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "shards_acknowledged": true,
    "index": "tr_logintracker"
}
```

Document is inserted into the index. Same can be seen using

```json
{
    "query": {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

Response

```json
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "tr_logintracker",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "6pJHe4QBPiDyvh1VwkiC",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "data": {
                        "vehicleownerid": 17,
                        "driverid": 21,
                        "vehicleid": 20,
                        "logintime": "2022-11-15 18:03:29",
                        "logout": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when the same is queried null result is getting fetched
Query

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         { "match": { "driverid" : 21 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```json
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

When checked /tr_logintracker/_mapping can see the below. Which does not look correct. The second set of entries is happening when we insert the document into the index.

```json
{
    "tr_logintracker": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "properties": {
                        "driverid": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "logintime": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "logout": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "vehicleid": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "vehicleownerid": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "driverid": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "logintime": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                },
                "logout": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "logouttime": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                },
                "vehicleid": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "vehicleownerid": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We also tried the option of dynamic mapping - getting the index created by the program which is inserting. Even in that case query is not fetching the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

It seems you have two entries for `driverid`,

- `data.driverid`
- `driverid`

From the document you showed the first time, you have `data.driverid: 21`.
But you seem to query `driverid` instead.

## Solution

This should work.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         { "match": { "data.driverid" : 21 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Root Cause

Most likely, you must be sending a document like below to Elasticsearch

```json
{
  "data": {
    "vehicleownerid": 17,
    "driverid": 21,
    "vehicleid": 20,
    "logintime": "2022-11-15 18:03:29",
    "logout": 0
  }
}
```

Where as you should be sending it like so

```json
{
  "vehicleownerid": 17,
  "driverid": 21,
  "vehicleid": 20,
  "logintime": "2022-11-15 18:03:29",
  "logout": 0
}
```

Comment: What we are using is the existing set of insert and search functions which are working for all other indexes. Only in this particular case we are facing the issue.
Why the second set of mapping entries are created? When same does not happen in other indexes.

Comment: Well this is the reason why you do not find any result in your query.

But indeed the root cause of you issue is during the ingestion of a document.

Answer (score 0):

From the `match_all` result, I can see that what you want to query stays inside the `data` object. So, instead of matching `driverid`, it should be `data.driverid`.

Your query then looks like this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         { "match": { "data.driverid" : 21 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Identified the root cause in data ingestion and fixed the same.